# Mimic private variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, object-literal

I am going through the book "JavaScript for the Ninja" and found the following text in the context of "How to mimic private variable in JavaScript via Object literal and classes"

The author show the example of implementing private variable via object literal:

[image]

And then mentioned the following:

> JavaScript doesn’t have private object properties. Instead, we can
>   mimic them through closures, by defining variables and specifying
>   object methods that will close over those variables. **Because with
>   object literals and classes our getter and setter methods aren’t
>   created within the same function scope as variables that we could use
>   for private object properties, we can’t do this**

Could someone help me in understand the highlighted text.

Comment: `on side note:-` classes do have private properties now. [`class MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields)

Comment: @CodeManiac private properties on classes won't work in Firefox, at all... not to mention they just make you type more.

Answer (score 4):

Even though they are technically not private Object properties, they might as well be seen as that in your mind, since they are scoped off in a constructor or class:

```js
function Tester(initVal){
  let privateProp = initVal;
  this.publicProp = 'testing';
  this.setPrivate = val=>{
    privateProp = val;
    return this;
  }
  this.getPrivate = ()=>{
    return privateProp;
  }
  this.setStatic = (prop, val)=>{
    if(typeof val === 'function')val.bind(this);
    this.constructor.prototype[prop] = val;
    return this;
  }
}
const test = new Tester('Initial Value');
console.log(test.publicProp); console.log(test.privateProp);
console.log(test.getPrivate());
console.log(test.setPrivate('See how it works?').getPrivate());
test.setStatic('cool', 'neat');
const test2 = new Tester;
console.log(test2.cool);
test.setStatic('fun', function(){
  return this.setStatic('staticProp', "Really, that's fantastic!");
});
test.fun(); console.log(test2.staticProp);
```

Comment: Why the author said "In object literal getter and setter methods aren’t created within the same function scope as variables that we could use for private object properties" - I did not get this statement

Comment: Without assigning the scope to a higher level outside the Object, Objects cannot have variables scoped outside of their methods. Constructors and classes have to be called `new` on before they become Objects, or they are just functions. I believe the author is incorrectly referring to a class or constructor as an Object, when writing about "private object properties". There really are no private Object properties in JavaScript. Note that assignment of a non-primitive value to a variable is just a reference to the non-primitive, not a `new` instance.